# How to only execute next command after first command is executed in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I have AutoHotKey script.

Currently my AHK script is running all the time. and it waits for user inputs.

if user presses 11 then do something.
if user presses 12 then do something else.

**current AHK script**

```
1::
Input Key, L1

if Key=1
    {
    Run C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\Users\username\Desktop\new.ps1
    ; How can I make this command run only after above script has finished executing?
}
```

Comment: I found out that we can run PS script by using this command `Run C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\new.ps1` now I just need help to run next command only after PS script is finished executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hotkeys like 1:: and then input key, you could create hotstrings:

```
:*:11::
RunWait xyz
Return

:*:12::
RunWait, abc
Return
```

Comment: robert, I can't do `:*:1:: Runwait xyz return` and `:*:11:: RunWait, abc Return` right ? or  can I ? I tried it would only do the first condition.

Comment: As soon as you hit the first condition "1", the first hotstring will execute. What I often do is make each code unique with a "\" at the end, thus :*:1\::  and :*:11\::  and :*:12\:: etc.. Instead of defining the end character with #Hotstring EndChars, I use various "end" characters based on the language (English, German, Dutch, French, Python, AHK, HTML, etc.) this way "r=" is "With Reagrds", "r\" is "Met vriendelijke groet", "r/" = "Mit Freundlichen Grüssen", "r[" is "Return", etc.

Comment: Thanks just to make sure. if I use `:*:1\::` I would need to press `1` and `\` correct?

Comment: I think you wanted to write 1\, but the \ was consumed by the back-ticks.

Comment: oh oky. so I think there is not way to do xyz by pressing 1 and do abc by pressing 11.

Comment: Unless you work with a timer. press 1 wait a few ms (e.g. 300) and if no other number has been pressed, execute 1, else execute 1n.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RunWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm)

*Unlike Run, RunWait will wait until Target is closed or exits, at which time ErrorLevel will be set to the program's exit code (as a signed 32-bit integer). Some programs will appear to return immediately even though they are still running; these programs spawn another process.*

Comment: Thanks, do instead of `Run C:\Windows\System32....` I should use `Runwait C:\Windows\System32....` ? just want to double check.